# "Vs." vs./v. "V."

Tags: meaning, orthography

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I abbreviate “versus”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5392/how-should-i-abbreviate-versus)

I came across this sentence the other day:

> In the case Lee v Knapp,...

And I was a bit confused, because shouldn't it be "vs."? I looked up the dictionary and it gave "vs.", as well as "v.". So my question is, which one is better/ more correct, and if so why? Would people understand you better if you used one or the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pretty standard in the legal world to refer to cases as *Plaintiff v. Defendant*. This includes even when speaking the name of a case: “plaintiff vee defendant”. For example, the landmark U.S. Supreme Court case regarding abortion, *Roe v. Wade*, is usually called “Roe vee Wade” when spoken, not “Roe versus Wade.”

In most other cases where you would abbreviate the word *versus*, such as in sporting matches, you would use the two-letter abbreviation *vs*.

Comment: In many courts the "v." is read as "and" because the case is concerning both the plaintiff and the defendant in a manner that isn't intended to be a competition (the initial focus is on finding/creating a win-win solution, and an adversarial "vs." {versus} attitude certainly may not be as helpful in this regard as an inclusive "v." {and} attitude).