# What does "v." stand for?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, conjunctions, acronyms

In in the following sentence, what does the "v." stand for?

> The new system was partially indebted to Stanley v. Georgia

Does it mean "Stanley and Georgia" or "Stanley against Georgia"?

Comment: does initial strike a bell?

Comment: It's a Latin abbreviation for _versus_, which means _against_. It's legal terminology, used to identify individual case decisions, and often the legal principles they define.

Comment: @vickyace, I can understand what do you mean? :)

Comment: @JohnLawler,  what does the convention of naming this legal decisions? Stanley and Georgia are two people in court? or what?

Comment: Don't know in this case, but the convention is that each name is the family, corporate, or official name of one of the parties in the case. If it was a criminal case, the governmental unit prosecuting will usually be named (i.e, _v. United States, v. Georgia_ -- State of Georgia), and such units can also be parties to civil suits, (_Brown v. Board of Education_ -- Topeka, Kansas Board of Education).

Comment: "v" can be an initial for a name such as victor, van, vicky and so on.
here, I think they are indebted to one man named Stanley V. Georgia for some favor he did or help he provided. unless there is more context, I'd say it is an initial.

Comment: @vickyace Nope. See my answer. Initials are uppercase, a lowercase *v.* points towards a legal case.

Comment: Related: (particularly the answers): http://english.stackexchange.com/q/52378/8019

Comment: Stanly Community College, (Albemarle, NC) versus University of Georgia (Athens, GA). The sport is not stated, so we can only speculate. The SEC has long been notorious for scheduling "cupcake games" against lesser opponents. But this particular mismatch looks to be truly beyond the pale.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In law, *v.* is an abbreviation for *versus* and law case citations are generally written in this format.

So it means the legal decision [*Stanley v. Georgia.*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanley_v._Georgia) The new system isn't indebted to Stanley nor Georgia, but rather the United States Supreme Court decision in that legal case.

Comment: can you explain more about it? Georgia is the name of a person, or Georgia is the name of the State?
what does the convention of naming this legal decisions?

Comment: Go to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanley_v._Georgia and for the official syllabus and opinions http://www.law.cornell.edu/supremecourt/text/394/557

Comment: @ArashMousavi If you follow the hyperlink, you'll see that the case was Robert Eli Stanley against the State of Georgia.

Comment: +1 The Latin term *versus* means *against*. The case name means *Stanley [a person] brought a lawsuit against Georgia [a state or state agency]*. While the legal community generally uses *v.* (in small letters), the common press often uses *vs.* to mean the same thing.

Comment: NB: in England, lawyers pronounce the "v" as "and", as in "Walsh v Lonsdale" said as "Walsh and Lonsdale". Just so you know.