# Preferred abbreviations of 'versus' according to Anglophone country?

Tags: abbreviations, legalese, variants

I am already aware that for example BE and AE have different opinions on using periods in abbreviations. Today, I am interested in variations among English speaking countries (specifically: UK, USA, Australia, South Africa) that may perhaps go further: the „correct“ abbreviation for „versus“ (in legal context). I suppose that there are at least four possibilities: „v.“, „v“, „vs.“, and „vs“. Perhaps there are even more (e.g., I know that in German the symbol „./.“ would be common)?
Is there a preference (possibly different for each of the countries in question)?
By observation, I would assume that the answer is „v.“ for the USA and „v“ for the rest (whereas „vs.“ or „vs“ would only be used for things like sport events)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I abbreviate "versus"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5392/how-should-i-abbreviate-versus) See also [v or vs for versus](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/366269/v-or-vs-for-versus)?

Comment: No, v. is used in the States and in the UK. See: Jarndyce v Jarndyce in Dickens' Bleak House.

Comment: Dickens's 1853 _Bleak House_. There does seem to be divided usage, plenty of examples of both _Jarndyce v. Jarndyce_ and _Jarndyce v Jarndyce_. Of course, this may not point towards what's actually happening in modern UK legalese, but just to the popularised usages.